# How to correct virtualenv command output

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I am learning to use virtual environments like and I realize that by using the use the **virtualenv** command:

```
virtualenv env_dj_cuatro
```

my virtual environment is created but at the same time it returns the following information at the end of its creation:

```
diego@computer:~/Documentos/django$ virtualenv env_dj_cuatro
created virtual environment CPython3.7.2.final.0-64 in 694ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/diego/Documentos/django/env_dj_cuatro, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/diego/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
diego@computer:~/Documentos/django$
```

I understand that it is as a result of what has been done but I do not understand why it is shown since when reviewing the guide tutorials like [this](https://youtu.be/N5vscPTWKOk?t=122) at no time does this information output occur

**How could I do to remove this information output?**

Thanks

Comment: see virtualenv --h for all options, you can use the quiet option: virtualenv env_dj_cuatro -q

Comment: @HenriqueForlani Is there a file where you can edit this behavior of the default command? for not to use -q

Comment: yes, take a look at : https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/cli_interface.html#conf-file, you can create a config file and have a verbose or quiet option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the info in the [link](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/cli_interface.html#configuration-file)

1. I excuete `virtualenv --help`

In the last line it indicates that to configure files they should create the file:

```
/home/diego/.config/virtualenv/virtualenv.ini active (the route changes according to the equipment)
```

2. We enter the file and add the following lines:

```
[virtualenv] 
verbose = 0
```

We save the changes and when creating new virtual environments the verbosity no longer appears at the end of the command.

Answer (score 0):

The `virtualenv --help` gives all the info:

```
verbosity:
  verbosity = verbose - quiet, default INFO, mapping => CRITICAL=0, ERROR=1, WARNING=2, INFO=3, DEBUG=4, NOTSET=5

  -v, --verbose                 increase verbosity (default: 2)
  -q, --quiet                   decrease verbosity (default: 0)
```

In your example, this would be:

`virtualenv --quiet env_dj_cuatro`

If you need to install requirements, the `pip` also has the `--quiet` option:

`pip install --quiet -r requirements.txt`